# Attempting to deploy my app (Node, React, Socketio) to Heroku gives me "sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

So I am trying to make my first react app. I have it working just fine locally. The problem is that I cannot upload my project to Heroku.

This is my app setup:
[my file arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pAgI.png). I built this starting with a create-react-app, wrapped that entire thing in a "client" folder, and created a normal node server arrangement [outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtWRE.png). I haven't touched my react app's package.json" except to add a socketio dependency, other than that it is exactly what [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) spits out.

I get this error on console when attempting to upload:
["sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFME.png)

I have gone through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support, but to no avail.

This is my "outside" package.json scripts and dependencies

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm run build"
},
"dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've not gotten my application to work yet HOWEVER I finally found something interesting.

This: https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node

Looks like a barebones application I can essentially my stuff to, and have it work on Heroku. I've not added my code yet, I'll report back.

**UPDATE:**

Yep, seems to get past this permission BS. Now I just have to deal with getting socket.io client to connect... -_-

Comment: The problem is when you push to heroku, it uses your start script... and that's not a legitimate start script for heroku... You can install nodemon as I suggested for development and then change your scripts like I've noted below... Let me know if it still doesn't work... At least you'll get closer...

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
  },
```

`npm run dev` will start your server and client in development mode...

You can also install [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to make your life easier...

Comment: Yes sir, same error; "sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied"

Comment: Can you post your server.js?